# wow.js прыгает при скроле

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, wow.js

Вот сайт:

https://style-plitka.ru

В работе использовал wow.js + animate.css
Добавлял к элементам и блокам эффект появления при скролинге. На десктопной версии всё в порядке, но при адаптации возникла проблема. Вот видео, в каких то местах происходят "прыжки вверх":

> [Видео](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/hU_3SNAhaNRxxQ)

Подключение animate.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
```

Подключение wow.js

```
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
```

Честно не знаю какой код привести в пример, в подключении ничего трудного нет и все отрабатывает. наверное вопрос к тем, кто с этим сталкивался. Ну вот к примеру код с формой которая точно прыгает:

```
<section class="stock">     <!-- Скидочка и заявка -->
    <img src="img/image-background/background_three.png" alt="layout" class="image-background image-background_stock">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="stock__grid">
            <div class="form form_stock wow animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft">
                <h2 class="title title_fz45 title_fz45_white form__title">
                    ЗАЯВКА
                </h2>
                <div class="title title_fz22 form__subtitle">
                    Оставьте заявку прямо сейчас
                </div>
                <form action="mailer/smart.php" class="form__wrapper">      <!-- Заявка -->
                    <div class="form__select">      <!-- Услуга -->
                        <select name="service" id="service" class="title title_fz15 title_fz15_black">
                            <option>Ремонт ванных</option>
                            <option>Укладка плитки</option>
                            <option>Фотоплитка</option>
                        </select>
                        <label for="service" class="title title_fz14 title_fz14_montserrat">Услуга</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form__input">   <!-- Площадь + Арес -->
                        <div class="form__block">
                            <input name="address" type="text" class="title title_fz15 title_fz15_black" placeholder="г. Москва, ул. Перовская, д.1, к.2">
                            <label for="address" class="title title_fz14 title_fz14_montserrat">Адрес</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form__block form__block_width">
                            <input name="square" type="number" class="title title_fz15 title_fz15_black" placeholder="15 м&#178;">
                            <label for="square" class="title title_fz14 title_fz14_montserrat">Площадь</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form__input">       <!-- Имя + Емаил -->
                        <div class="form__block">
                            <input name="email" type="email" class="title title_fz15 title_fz15_black" placeholder="example@inbox.ru">
                            <label for="email" class="title title_fz14 title_fz14_montserrat">Ваша почта</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form__block form__block_width">
                            <input name="name" type="text" class="title title_fz15 title_fz15_black" placeholder="Иван">
                            <label for="name" class="title title_fz14 title_fz14_montserrat">Ваше имя</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form__input">   <!-- Телефон + Кнопка -->
                        <div class="form__block">
                            <input name="phone" class="title title_fz15 title_fz15_black" required placeholder="+7 999 999-99-99">
                            <label for="phone" class="title title_fz14 title_fz14_montserrat">Ваш телефон</label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="button button_form title title_fz15 title_fz15_font">
                            Отправить
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form__input">
                        <input name="check" type="checkbox" checked required>
                        <div class="title title_fz15 title_fz15_font title_fz15_unset form__check">Согласие на обработку <a href="confidentiality.html">персональных данных</a></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="stock__block">      <!-- Скидка -->
                <div class="stock__wrapper">
                    <h2 class="title title_black title_fz80 title_fz80_media stock__title">
                        СКИДКА
                    </h2>
                    <div class="title title_gradient title_fz120 stock__procent">
                        10%
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="titile title_gradient title_fz30 title_fz30_media stock__subtitle wow animate__animated animate__fadeInRight">
                    При заказе с сайта
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Пока искал решение, наткнулся на одну историю:
Если прописать overflow-x: hidden; для всех элементов

```
* {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

То скролл получается плавным, все работает как надо, прыжков нет, но появляются полосы прокрутки в тех блоках/элементах, где происходят прыжки. Это наталкивает меня на мысли что дело в ширине, но как применить эту находку, я не знаю. Честно, очень хочу вникнуть и разобраться почему так происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Решением оказалось, создать div с классом

Классу дать свойство  overflow со значением hidden

И элемент/блок у которых прописана анимация оборачивать в этот div

В общем манипуляции с этой обёрткой принесли результат, анимация теперь практически везде плавная.
Пока пытался сделать заметил, что прыжки происходят только там, где анимация подразумевает сдвиг вправо/влево.
Видимо для четкой анимации без прыжков wow.js и animate.css требуется блок с определенной шириной/высотой

Надеюсь это решение кому то поможет, а то реально сутки был в ступоре.